# Vector3.MoveTowards Putting Object in Wrong Place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, my objects never translate the correct amount. Why is that? I've tried using other functions but they don't animate the same way the below function does. So how can I set it so that it translates exactly 200 pixels below where it was previously.

**UPDATE:**
Since I haven't found a solution yet, I am providing a more in-depth explanation of the problem.

I have 6 UIImages, all of them are attached to a script called "LogDrop". There is also a GameControl script, once the user does something, a boolean called "active" is set to "true". In the "LogDrop" script, the update function is continuously running and checking if "active" is set to true, and if it is, the logs are all supposed to drop down 300 spaces.

When I start the program, the user triggers the active boolean and the logs move down BUT NOT 300 spaces.

My current code for the Update is this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (active)
    {
        if (!positionSet)
        {
            endPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 300, transform.position.z);
            positionSet = true;
        }
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, endPosition) > 0.00001)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, endPosition, 250 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            active = false;
            positionSet = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program and "active" is triggered, the logs move down 730.8 spaces even. I don't know where the value 730.8 is coming from... Once the logs move and finish moving, "active" is set back to false. However, when the user triggers the boolean again, the logs refuse to move again even though the function runs again.

Comment: Is it possible that something is setting `positionSet` to `false` unintentionally? Could you post more code for context?

Comment: @derHugo Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) calculates and returns a position between the current and target position. (the first and second parameter). The third parameter is the distance (or amount) to move toward the target position per call.

If you want your object to move exactly 200 units each call, you'll have to make sure that the third parameter is equal or over 200f.

However, you are using the wrong function for your purpose.

In fact, you could simply set the position directly

```js
var endPosition = new Vector3(
  transform.position.x, 
  transform.position.y - 200, 
  transform.position.z);
  
transform.position = endPosition;
```

Edit:

According to Vector3.MoveTowards documentation, your code should just work as you wanted. (moving your object and stop at the endPosition)

I suppose that wasn't the case, that why you're here. I may be able to offer you this little hacky solution.

```js
void Update()
{
    if(active)
    {
        if(!positionSet)
        {
            endPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 200, transform.position.z);
            positionSet = true;
        }
        var step = 250 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, endPosition) < step) {
          transform.position = endPosition;
        }else {
          transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, endPosition, step);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to be an animation though

Comment: I see, the documentation said `If the current position is already closer to the target than maxDistanceDelta, the value returned is equal to target;` which your code should just work. Perhaps, I can offer you a little hacky code. I'll edit my answer.